# Find duplicates between 2 columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if someone could help. suppose we have a dataframe in pandas

one column contains Frame number and the other column contains a tuple of ID codes:  Frame 1   (10,5)
Frame 2 (10,5)
Frame 3 (10,5)
Frame 4 (80,5)
Frame 5 (80,5)
Frame 6 (80,6)

I want to group them by the ID codes.  So if I use the groupby('ID Codes')
panda groups it like: Group 1. [(10,5),(10,5), (10,5]. Group 2 [(80,5), (80,5)] Group 3 [(80,6)]but what I want is that all of them grouped together since they have one value intersecting them. For example 5 appears in both 10 and 80 in frame 3 and 4, respectively . 80 appears in Frame 5 and 6 respectively.  Any way to do this by any chance..I tried a Jaccardi similarity between frames to do the group

A better example is shown below. The input panda frame is:

| Frame_number | Color_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Frame 1 | (10,5) |
| Frame 1 | (11,8) |
| Frame 1 | (12,9) |
| Frame 2 | (10,5) |
| Frame 2 | (11,8) |
| Frame 2 | (12,9) |
| Frame 3 | (10,5) |
| Frame 3 | (11,8) |
| Frame 3 | (12,9) |
| Frame 4 | (80,5) |
| Frame 4 | (11,8) |
| Frame 4 | (12,9) |
| Frame 5 | (80,5) |
| Frame 5 | (11,8) |
| Frame 5 | (12,9) |
| Frame 6 | (80,6) |
| Frame 6 | (11,8) |
| Frame 6 | (12,9) |

As Output, I want to group them like this :

Group 1:
[(10,5), (80,5), (80,6)]

Group2:
[(11,8)]

Group 3:
[(12,9)]

Comment: please add minimal reproductible example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.